# Logging a Node.js-Azure app, using Bot Framework

Tags: node.js, azure, logging, botframework

I have a Node application (Bot Framework bot) hosted on Azure. What's the best way to log information for debugging? For example, as far as i'm aware, using `console.log()` isn't helpful because there is no console to look at in Azure. I also do not want to call tons of `session.send()` to the client.

So whats the best way to get some sort of debug logging?

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage the Diagnostic Log extension on Azure Web Apps. Login your web app in Azure portal(https://ms.portal.azure.com/). Click on Diagnostic logs in settings option and Turn On Application logging in Diagnostic Logs Tab.
[image]

And then you can login the Kudu console site of your web app(`https://<Your_Webapp_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole`) and browse to your Application folder(`D:\home\LogFiles\Application folder`). 
[image]

Otherwise, you can click the `Diagnostic dump` on the top nav bar of the kudu console site to download the log files.
[image]

On the other hand, you can use the `Log stream` tool on the Azure portal(https://ms.portal.azure.com/) for a real time debugging online.
[image]

At last, you can integrate a 3rd part node.js log modules, such like [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) into your application. And catch the logs into your own log file.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: How to log the message ? I tried with console.log and nothing appears in the kudu portal. Also I changed the log level to verbose and added IISNode file but logs not appearing anywhere

Comment: @Rebornx, please try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-nodejs-debug

Answer (score 1):

This guide seems to answer your question: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-nodejs-debug. (If not, please provide additional info about what you'd like to achieve.)