# Where can i see logs that are generated by node js code in bot framework ?

Tags: botframework

I am able to see running logs by logging to the build and open online editor from Azure but here i can only see running logs. But how do i see past logs like 1 day back logs or 2 days back logs. When some one reports some issue i want to go through the logs and figure out what back end service caused issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logging a Node.js-Azure app, using Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470047/logging-a-node-js-azure-app-using-bot-framework)

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Take a look at stuartd's link listed in the comment. It has some really useful logging options.
2. If are looking to log bot activity (like shown below) that is returned from the logging middleware, I would suggest capturing that data and storing it for analysis later.
3. Another option is [BotBuilder-Instrumentation](https://github.com/Azure/botbuilder-instrumentation) which may fit your needs.

(Please forgive the attached image. SO isn't playing nice with my code.)

[image]